# Car TCO Computation how it's being computed

Tags: car

[TCO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0OBL.png)

From the picture posted above, I'm trying to figure out how the TCO is being computed. The efficiency is the MPG, for which I believe is a hybrid car.

14275 / 56
= 254.9107142857142857

14275 / 56 * 2.82
= 718.8482142857142857
I get that it's $718.84 for gas / whole year but still not sure how to get the TCO

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's what I'm saying, this was for a programming assignment though the example the professor handed didn't have any formula etc haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers check out, if they're supposed to be the purchase price of the car, plus 5 years worth of gas, minus the resale value.

25,956 + 5 x 718 - 10,744 = 18,802

They *yearly* cost of ownership would be one fifth of those $18.8 K.

However, this doesn't take into account the cost of **insuring** the car, the cost of the **maintenance** the car will need to keep running for 5 years, or the cost of any road **tolls** or car ownership **taxes** that apply in your location. So it's not, by far, a *total* cost of ownership.

Comment: is there a specific reason you're using decimals for the prices, otherwise I'll take it 

Comment: @tameer: I regressed to the thousand separators used in my native language. Now fixed.